# How to open JFileChooser with predefined size

Tags: java, swing, size, jfilechooser, fileopendialog

```
chooser = new JFileChooser();
chooser.setSize(300, 200);
if (chooser.showOpenDialog(this) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
.......
}
```

This doesn't work.
Always opens in default size.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try `chooser.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 200))`

Comment: It is actually chooser.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 600)); and it works. Thanks

Comment: Sorry about leaving off the Dimension.  I just typed the method from memory.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a solution would be to extend the JFileChooser class and overload the constructor with the new setSize method. Not sure if this will work. I know you can extend the very basic JDialog to create custom dialogs and calling setSize there worked for me last time I tried it.